# What is a dislocation defect in metals as opposed to a grain boundary?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, topological-defects

Almost all metals found in nature are polycrystalline so that there must be grain boundaries. My understanding is that individual grains are tiny defectless crystals and different grains are rotated w.r.t each other at the grain boundaries where the periodicity is interrupted. Are the grain boundaries same as line defects or in particular, same as dislocations? Even if they are not same, does the polycrystalline nature of metals i.e., the existence of grain boundaries imply the existence of line defects? The answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368262/why-are-metals-malleable-and-ductile) tends to suggest that.

Comment: No, dislocations are line defects, grain boundaries are 2D defects. Grain boundaries can be constructed out of some arrangement of screw and edge dislocations, most easily seen for high-symmetry boundaries.

Comment: @JonCuster Can I say that the polycrystalline nature of metal causes it to have line defects? The answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368262/why-are-metals-malleable-and-ductile impresses upon me that metals being polycrystalline must have line defects. Is that wrong?

Comment: Take a bicrystal, an intensively studied system, which is two perfect crystals joined with a twist boundary between them. The twist boundary is an array of screw dislocations. No line defects _in_ the two crystals on either side are required. So, you need line defects to construct the grain boundary, but they are not required in the interior of the otherwise perfect crystals.

Comment: You can have either a polycrystal or a single crystal with either a large or small dislocation density within the crystalline region. The two aspects are not intrinsically related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grain boundaries are 2-dimensional [crystallographic defects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_defect). Dislocations are 1-dimensional crystallographic defects. Small angle grain boundaries (<15°) can be considered to be composed of an array of step dislocations. Large angle grain boundaries are more complicated.

Comment: I didn't get the answer to my question yet. My question was whether the existence of grain boundaries imply the existence of dislocations. Thanks.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 - Small-angle grain boundaries consist of an array of dislocations.  Therefore, the existence of such a grain boundary does imply the existence of dislocations! See C. Kittel, Introduction to Solid State Physics, 8th ed., 2005, Chapter 21, Figure 11.