# A metallic container when hammered deforms but a wine glass when falls or hammered breaks. Why?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, glass, amorphous-solids

A wine glass breaks when it falls from hand or is hammered. But when a metallic object (say, a container) is hammered, it only deforms without breaking. Why? Is it somehow related to the fact that glass is amorphous while metal is not?

Comment: Related: [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368262/why-are-metals-malleable-and-ductile/368298#368298](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368262/why-are-metals-malleable-and-ductile/368298#368298)

Comment: And yet metals can exhibit brittle fracture as well...

Comment: "But a metal glass when hammered..." - Does your question involve metallic glasses or just ordinary crystalline metals? You say "metal glass" in this one sentence but the rest of your post makes it sound like you're just asking about ordinary metals.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I've made some edits to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

at room temperature, there are nanoscale deformation mechanisms available to most metals which allow them to withstand plastic flow without fracture. these deformation mechanisms (primarily dislocation glide and climb) are absent in glasses, which tend instead to shatter when stressed in tension.