# Why isn't the tensile/compressive strength of a material dependent on its atomic bond strength?

Tags: material-science

The melting or sublimation point of a material indicates the strength of the bonds between its molecules being high, as the material remains solid despite the amount of heat energy present. Carbon, at 3500 degrees melting (or sublimation) point is only a few hundred degrees below the most temperature resistant material of all (which contains carbon). But it is not used in construction, and its properties are only remarkable when in the form of graphene or used in a composite. Metal alloys, on the other hand, may not have almighty bond strength (well it's less than carbon) but end up being use widely in aerospace (and deep space) and many other applications. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are metals malleable and ductile?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/368298/146039) Material selection depends on many factors other than melting point and yield/ultimate strength.

Comment: Re, "it [carbon] is not used in construction." Not entirely sure what you're saying, but some bleeding edge aerospace applications use a material that is variously called "[carbon-carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforced_carbon%E2%80%93carbon)" or "carbon fibre reinforced carbon" (CFRC) or "reinforced carbon carbon" (RCC). From a chemist's point of view, the material is nothing but pure carbon, but from a materials science point of view, it's considerably more interesting than, for example, a bag of charcoal.

Comment: I am agreeing with the other close voters that, as is currently written, it is not clear what would constitute an acceptable answer to this question. It seems to be difficult to start answering this question, even if we ignore the categorical problem that, actually, it is the mesoscopic domain-domain bonds, rather than the microscopic bonds, that determine the general strength properties, unless you can make huge single crystals. Please revise the question.

Answer (score 1):

Most microscopic crystals of metal which make up a macroscopic piece of it contain defects called *dislocations* in which the atoms in the immediate vicinity of the dislocation are imperfectly matched up with their nearest neighbors. when that piece of metal is stressed, the dislocations are the first things to let go and so their presence reduces the strength of the material to a level far below that which would be represented by the interatomic forces of attraction alone.

Engineering alloys like steel and aluminum are strengthened by inhibiting the movement of dislocations when stressed, on the microscopic level. You can also increase the strength of a part by forming it from a single crystal instead of a huge collection of microcrystals because the boundaries between adjacent grains themselves represent mismatched zones that are weaker than the material inside the grain- as well as acting as sites where dislocations are generated as the part gets stressed.

Answer (score 0):

The molecules interact with each other with bonds which are not necessarily equal to the strength of the bonds within the molecule.

The physical arrangement of the molecules within a material determine the strength of a material in that impurity molecules, dislocation, voids etc will contribute to the strength of the material.

Thus strength is not the only property of a material which is important.
For example there might be a consideration of electrical and thermal conductivity, corrosion resistance, density, ductility, elasticity, fracture resistance, hardness, creep resistance $\ldots$

Comment: Firstly, I meant the bonds between molecules. Also why is the arrangement of molecules in the material important? Are the bonds between molecules assymetrical?

Comment: If you have a microscopic crack, molecular bonds across crack very weak, in a material which is stressed, that crack might get bigger and lead to a failure of the material., which is a characteristic of a brittle material under tension.  As you know glass is brittle, sharp edges are formed when it fractures, but place thin strands of glass in a resin and you have a strong composite, fibre glass. Individual fibres might break by the crack responsible for the failure cannot the propagate to an adjacent fibre due to the presence of the resin between the fibres.